# Extrair grupos com regex

Tags: java, regex

Preciso extrair o session e a data da linha abaixo, sendo que a data eu tenho separado com traço e barra.

Os patterns funcionam corretamente individualmente mas quando tento extrair os dois, nada vem.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{8}-\\w{4}-\\w{4}-\\w{4}-\\w{12}) (\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4} | \\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher("{E4AE5831-548B-4429-CB99-2429334A6348} | 16/03/2017 00:59:35 | [ColetaCPFVerificaColetaInicialReportCode] : [O seguinte prompt será vocalizad");

    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```

Comment: Editei sua pergunta removendo saudações conforme [este tópico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-agradecimentos), para ficar de acordo com o [formato do site](/tour)

Comment: Obrigado! ... vou prestar mais atenção :)

Comment: Se sua ou outra resposta foi satisfatória, você pode aceitá-la como resposta da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O padrão deve corresponder a todos os caracteres no texto.

- Entre a *session* e a data não há espaço, mas `"} | "`.
- As duas alternativas de datas não devem ter espaços entre eles: `(data1|data2)`.

#### Expressão regular

```
^\{([\dA-F]{8}(?:-[\dA-F]{4}){4}[\dA-F]{8})} \| (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

**Descrição**

- `^` - [Circunflexo](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/circunflexo.html#2_3_1) que casa o começo da cadeia de caracteres.
- `\{` - [Escape](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/escape.html#2_4_1) que casa uma chave literal `"{"`.
- `([\dA-F]{8}(?:-[\dA-F]{4}){4}[\dA-F]{8})` - [Grupo de captura](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/grupo.html#2_4_3) ([*capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) que permite referenciar o texto casado (usando [`Matcher#group(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-)) com:

  - `[\dA-F]{8}(?:-[\dA-F]{4}){4}[\dA-F]{8}` - O formato da *session*, permitindo apenas caracteres hexadecimais. Usamos um [grupo sem captura](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/modernosos-fantasma.html#3_5_2) para salvar alguns caracteres.
- `} \|` - Casa o literal `"} | "`.
- `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - [Grupo de captura](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/grupo.html#2_4_3) com duas [alternativas](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/ou.html#2_4_2):

  - Alternativa 1: `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}`.
  - Alternativa 2: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`.

#### Código

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "^\\{([\\dA-F]{8}(?:-[\\dA-F]{4}){4}[\\dA-F]{8})\\} \\| (\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}|\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})";
final String linha = "{E4AE5831-548B-4429-CB99-2429334A6348} | 16/03/2017 00:59:35 | [ColetaCPFVerificaColetaInicialReportCode] : [O seguinte prompt será vocalizad";

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher m = p.matcher(linha);

if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

**Resultado**

```
E4AE5831-548B-4429-CB99-2429334A6348
16/03/2017
```

Pode testar aqui: http://ideone.com/qgRtt8

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava interpretando erroneamente a forma como o pattern trabalha.

A solução foi informar os caracteres entre os dois grupos que eu desejo extrair inserindo o quantificador

```
.*
```

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{8}-\\w{4}-\\w{4}-\\w{4}-\\w{12}).*(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4} | \\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher("{E4AE5831-548B-4429-CB99-2429334A6348} | 16/03/2017 00:59:35 | [ColetaCPFVerificaColetaInicialReportCode] : [O seguinte prompt será vocalizad");
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Pode falhar com `{E4AE5831-548B-4429-CB99-2429334A6348} | 16/03/2017 00:59:35 | [Coleta] : [O seguinte 1111-22-33 casa a última data`